# Should i remove french special characters and apostrophes

Tags: nlp, data-cleaning, preprocessing, bert

I am working on a french text preprocessing task, in order to prepare the data to train an NLP model. But I do not know if it is better to remove french special characters and apostrophes or keep them. Example:

```
Malgré que j'ai tellement aimé ce boulot je veut démissionner
```

Becomes

```
Malgre que jai tellement aime ce boulot je veut demissionner
```

I have also noticed that most lemmatization libraries for french text are not at all efficient so i was wondering if I could skip this step, and also skip the stopwords removal step.
In general the preprocessing steps will be :

1. Remove URLs and Emails
2. Demojize Emojis
3. Transform number into text (6->six)
4. Removal of all special characters including french special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the data volume you have.

As far as I know, there are 2 cases to have good NLP models:

- Either you have plenty of data (>10 GB as a raw order of magnitude) so that you can build accurate models, even if there are special characters.
- Either you don't have a lot of data (~1GB or less) and you have to simplify it as much as possible, and even improve it (for instance, replace ; by ,). In other words, you compensate the quantity with quality.

Keep in mind that data complexity is correlated with data quantity. The more the data is complex, the more data you need.

In conclusion, if you have a lot of data, you should keep the accents as they are necessary to make differences between words, and some words in french are different with or without accents (ex: tâche, tache, etc.), but any model would differentiate them according to their context (cf. attention mechanism).
If you don't have a lot of data, removing accents would be better, because it would reduce the vocabulary corpus, and hence improve the learning.

Note: There are very good NLP spell checkers available to recover the correct spelling with accents.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a language question than a data science question. Generally speaking, you should remove them. However, I am uncertain as I do not speak French, and you should be careful if there are cases in which the words with and without special characters have different meanings. Also, do not forget to remove stop words.